# How to import submodule from maven module?

Tags: java, maven

I have a question. I have a library for displaying and editing objects, this library contains mudules:

- OEADL-EXCEPTIONS - this module contains exceptions for my library
- OEADL-ANNOTATIONS - this module contains necessary annotations for classes to markup to be handled by my library
- OEADL-SWING - this module using for displaying and editing objects(this module imports OEADL-EXCEPTION, OEADL-ANNOTATIONS)

All these modules are submodules of the my library. And I want to use, for example, only module OEADL-ANNOTATIONS on server side, OEADL-SWING - on client side
How can I do it ? Is there an opportunity for using
Because I don't know how to import only submodule from module in Maven.

Comment: Do you have a pom.xml for each module? Then you can include the modules you want exactly where  you need it without unnecessary modules.

Comment: I don't want to do another project for oeadl-annotations, because this module is the part of my library. And i want to change it, only if I change all my library or if I add new functions

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer yes, I have

Comment: What do you mean by `import` ? Do you mean to use that module (jar file)?

Comment: @khmarbaise I mean for exmple, add dependency in project, where the part of this library will be used(OEADL-ANNOTATIONS or OEADL-SWING)

Comment: Create a Maven multi-module project. Each module lies in its own directory and is compiled to a JAR. Then you can define a dependency on whichever JAR you want. You cannot define dependencies on parts of JARs.